# How to extract .depot file on HPUX?

Tags: extract, hp-ux

How can I extract extract a .depot file on HPUX?

The `.depot` file is a tarred dir stucture, with some of the files gzipped under the same name as original.

Note that my environment is quite limited - I can't have root, I don't have `swinstall`.

http://forums13.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447627+1259826031876+28353475&threadId=1143807

At best, the solution should work on Linux too.

I have tried to `untar` and `gunzip -f -r -d -v --suffix= .`
But the problem is that the gzipped files have no suffix, so in the end, gzip deletes them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was relatively easy:

```
for f in `find -type f` ; do
    mv $f $f.gz
    gunzip $f.gz
done
```